# Summing a sub-square of a quarter of an infinite chessboard

Tags: code-golf, integer, bitwise

## Description of the problem

Imagine a quarter of an infinite chessboard, as in a square grid, extending up and right, so that you can see the lower left corner. Place a 0 in there. Now for every other cell in position `(x,y)`, you place the smallest non-negative integer that hasn't showed up in the column `x` or the row `y`.

It can be shown that the number in position `(x, y)` is `x ^ y`, if the rows and columns are 0-indexed and `^` represents bitwise `xor`.

### Task

Given a position `(x, y)`, return the sum of all elements below that position and to the left of that position, inside the square with vertices `(0, 0)` and `(x, y)`.

## The input

Two non-negative integers in any sensible format. Due to the symmetry of the puzzle, you can assume the input is ordered if it helps you in any way.

## Output

The sum of all the elements in the square delimited by `(0, 0)` and `(x, y)`.

## Test cases

```
5, 46 -> 6501
0, 12 -> 78
25, 46 -> 30671
6, 11 -> 510
4, 23 -> 1380
17, 39 -> 14808
5, 27 -> 2300
32, 39 -> 29580
14, 49 -> 18571
0, 15 -> 120
11, 17 -> 1956
30, 49 -> 41755
8, 9 -> 501
7, 43 -> 7632
13, 33 -> 8022
```

Comment: vaguely [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41984/75323)

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious if there's a bitwise way to express this without summing everything.

Comment: We'll see what you guys come up with :)

Comment: The main diagonal is [A224923](https://oeis.org/A224923).

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{sum [X+^] 0 X..@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFchOkI7LlbBQCFCT88hvvZ/cWKlQpqCqY6Cidl/AA)

The sum of the bitwise xor between all numbers in the range 0 to all inputs.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:sum(k/-~x^k%-~x for k in range(~x*~y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7daoQwEIXvfYphoWDKlObXRMHbPkEvSyGl2i7uxkVdUEp9dTuJu/QimXwz55zMZZm@@yC3tn7bTv788elhxqUar@e8e35a5/fugW5o@wE6OAYYfPhq8nV@XBfGtqH@eR2uTQUHPx4QXvxpjBD6Cajxm0UbxWETrXmWg0HQBUJhuGBIzBGERLAukrxNFS/sPiYQAsEInlAjSEUt5RILS9qSWDueAmK8tFHEk0DJXSBLc3NQgo4OZ@z/AiYusc/ps5gqSlOkAL7rtbDGJL1DAGrc9yetpo1soWTy01vRcVxGZlUGl@EYpnxGWBBaqgu717pu2PYH)

The usual [div-mod trick for iterating over two ranges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41217/20260). Unfortunately, since we want inclusive ranges, we need to raise each input by 1, which we do with `-~`. Thanks to Bubbler for saving 2 bytes by cancelling the minuses on `-~x*-~y`.

Python 3 would be a byte longer using `//`. I tried to use the 3.8 walrus operator to cut down on the `-~x` repetition, without success.

**55 bytes**

```python
f=lambda m,n:m|n>0and(m^n)+f(m-1,n)+f(m,n-1)-f(m-1,n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVcnzyq3Js/OIDEvRSM3Lk9TO00jV9dQB8LQydM11NSFigCZ/wuKMvNKFNI0DHQMDTS5YDxjHVMEx1zHXPM/AA)

A cute recursion, but unfortunately longer. This doesn't use anything particular about XOR -- this same method can be used to add up any two-variable function over a rectangle. The base case `m|n>0` terminates with zero when either `m` or `n` becomes negative, or (harmlessly) when both are zero.

This will time out on larger test cases due to the huge degree of recursive branching.

**52 bytes**

```python
f=lambda m,n,b=1:m|n>0and(m^n)+f(m,n-1)*b+f(m-1,n,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVcnTyfJ1tAqtybPziAxL0UjNy5PUztNAyiua6iplQRi6hoCFRlo/i8oyswrUUjTMNAxNNDkgvGMdUwRHHMdc83/AA)

A similar shorter recursion. The idea is that we can recursively travel left or down, but once we've gone left, we set to flag `b` to zero and ignore the results of any further travel down. The result is that we travel to each cell in the rectangle exactly one, like this:

```python
O < O < O < O
            v
O < O < O < O
            v
O < O < O < O
```

**Other ideas**

Here are some partial ideas that didn't lead to decent golfs, but maybe someone can make use of them.

The one-dimensional summation (on a half-open range)

```python
w=lambda i,n:sum(i^j for j in range(n))
```

can be expressed recursively as

```python
w=lambda i,n:i+n and 4*w(i/2,n/2)+n%2*(n^i^1)+n/2
```

(Python 2 used for floor division.)

We also have an efficient formula

$$f(m-1,n-1) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {\frac{m n - |m \odot 2^{i}||n \odot 2^{i}|}{2} 2^i}$$

where \$ \odot k\$ is the symmetric modulo-\$(2k)\$ operator mapping to the range from \$-k\$ to \$k\$. This summation can be truncated where \$2^i\$ is bigger than the inputs, since further terms will be zero.

Comment: [`-~x*-~y` can be `~x*~y`](https://tio.run/##RY7daoQwEIXvfYphoWDKlObXRMHbPkEvSyGl2i7uxkVdUEp9dTuJu/QimXwz55zMZZm@@yC3tn7bTv788elhxqUar@e8e35a5/fugW5o@wE6OAYYfPhq8nV@XBfGtqH@eR2uTQUHPx4QXvxpjBD6Cajxm0UbxWETrXmWg0HQBUJhuGBIzBGERLAukrxNFS/sPiYQAsEInlAjSEUt5RILS9qSWDueAmK8tFHEk0DJXSBLc3NQgo4OZ@z/AiYusc/ps5gqSlOkAL7rtbDGJL1DAGrc9yetpo1soWTy01vRcVxGZlUGl@EYpnxGWBBaqgu717pu2PYH).

Comment: Also, an attempt to remove some `-~`s turned out to be [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEITvfoolULDSDdGvJRt87RP0WAoutdvgxA62AxYheXV3JSf0IKRvd2Y0Zz/99p1cmvJjOVanr@8KZvTFeDml7d5/ti/@VTT9AC0cOhiq7qdOd/d56xnbzdv7vJfLUF7fh0tdwKYaNwhv1XEM0PUT0OCWBDdFYh0S0iQFg6AzhMxwwZCYIwiJYF0g@dgqntl1TSAEghE8okaQikbKRRaWtDmxdjwGhHhpg4hHgZKrQObm4aAEHRzO2P8CJpRY9/RZSBW5yWIAX/VaWGOi3iEADZ79Saupkc2UjH56KzqOy8CsSOA8HLopnRE8QkO3Z8@7LGu2/AE).

Comment: Good work here! +1

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Array[BitXor,{##}+1,0,Plus]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d@xqCixMtopsyQiv0inWlm5VttQx0AnIKe0OFbtv6Y1V0BRZl5JNEhC1y7NQVk5Vs3BwaGai6vaVEfBxKxWh6vaQEfB0AjEMIIIcXHV/gcA)

Comment: Nice use of the fourth argument!

Comment: Wow, this is incredibly short for a Mathematica submission! +1

Comment: You can save three bytes by taking a list as input

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{(0..y+x*y+=1).sum{|r|r/y^r%y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDbasMwEETf9yv00mLXiqzV3W2cH2nTkF4CAScNcgMWtr/dlRTSl4XDzOws668fYTm0y2oz0DAWnLFQDU@harFk/fU0Tn7ydXj3D2Gel/V6GAbWHc/fPTvtL@PUTTFFfdux/nN/Luq3r6ouk1Q8Pv/@7I7ly4W8JsshzS312xk0JcqQ1YYYzRE4JSgSWQfiX5LcWAQTNUyokYOiRMgEKB0HtJTIJqNy3KWlwiYUknOQ4q6KRid3DKub22l7K9UZRRQxUs5iow1IfvcqtFqDoyRTOjaWqnyDNVIAytiS0XEhIL5m@QM)

Comment: What is the `|r|` doing?

Comment: @RGS It defines the name of the variable which is used inside the block, iterating over every value between `0` and `y+x*y+=1`. Kind of like `for( r = 0; r <= y+x*(y+1); r = r + 1 ){`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 15 bytes

```apl
+/,{⊥≠/⊤⍵}¨⍳1+⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY67SgNBFIZrz1OcPoacy9x2e4VUPkNgN4sQNkEsFLH1EojYWAoWCvbiC/go8yLrzM6m/Ob7@Oesdpt5c7vabLt5e3Pd9k3bDPHlbXkRH14J4tPjepgtTu/i/is@fyzi/jMefu//vuPhh2epG1KRqw7q8@0VXmK97DFLCydrqM/6Jj3nYOjAonGY5Ds6SwyELAV9ABllBiXnGRwyF2mZwKBoIdZAwB61KmgChTQsvmhRIlA5aqlszg2aKQ/Wjx/baU2SZUx7I1XWgdIxNuythYAVToekmz2a6RDvVIAVVUcMJPIP)

Full program.

#### How it works

```apl
+/,{⊥≠/⊤⍵}¨⍳1+⎕
              ⎕  ⍝ Take a pair [x y] from stdin
           ⍳1+   ⍝ Generate indices from [0 0] to [x y] inclusive
   {     }¨      ⍝ For each pair,
       ⊤⍵        ⍝   Convert two numbers into two-column bit matrix
                 ⍝   (each column is binary representation of each number)
     ≠/          ⍝   Reduce each row with not-equals (XOR)
    ⊥            ⍝   Convert the resulting binary representation back to integer
+/,              ⍝ Sum all elements and implicit print
```

Comment: Nice APL submission +1

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ý`δ^˜O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NyEc1viTs/x//8/2lTHxCwWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w3MTzm2JOz3H/7/O/@hoUx0Ts1idaAMdQyMgZQTlmukYGgIpEx0jYyBlaK5jbAmkTXWMzIGUsRGEa2iiY2IJ0WsK4hrqGIKlDSDCFjog0lzHBGyEsY6xcWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý       # Push a list in the range [0,value] for each value in the (implicit) input-pair
 `      # Push both these lists separated to the stack
  δ     # Apply double-vectorized:
   ^    #  XOR them together
    ˜O  # And then take the flattened sum
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission! Was it after or before the morning meetings? ;)

Comment: @RGS Uhh, dunno anymore haha. I think slightly before based on that '13 hours ago'. ;)

Comment: Alright! I see you like golfing :D

Comment: @RGS What makes you think that, haha. Is it my multiple answers a day? My 65k+ rep? My 7+ gold badges? Me joining 3.5 years ago, but still active today? xD But yes, I indeed like golfing while I'm waiting for things to compile/build at work.

Comment: Oh man, I wish I was coding in a compiled language :P I am gonna propose that back at work, so that I can enjoy some code golf while everything builds...

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>23</s> 17 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

```
1#.1#.XOR/&(i.,])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu7CsJAFET7fMUhislC3OTuI3EDVoKVIKSysRKD2vj/1XpXmGGGeXxybZuV40xDx8Cs3FtOy@WcZWMVt@vS79q37e4mm4rq@Xh9WXtqgVYiji2RMOpRHO5vR0QIOI9M@KS9U3XFSiCkso1lU@qhBAcSE0EPHu9N/gE)

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 25 bytes

```
{+/2/'~=/'(64#2)\''+!1+x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYs7DoMwEESvMlGKBVnI7Md2yCo3SU1DQYsUJVc3xmlGejPztmnfal2fnxAl0u8Vach2l/FNFG4cjm9daUiw7JjB4pA/ZDA7DKIOLtDFkSDFodKBDbZ0JzXg9mnT3LsHWhTYZSpUx3oC)

Most probably can be golfed further.

Comment: [J, 17 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYu7CsJAFET7fMUhislC3OTuI3EDVoKVIKSysRKD2vj/1XpXmGGGeXxybZuV40xDx8Cs3FtOy@WcZWMVt@vS79q37e4mm4rq@Xh9WXtqgVYiji2RMOpRHO5vR0QIOI9M@KS9U3XFSiCkso1lU@qhBAcSE0EPHu9N/gE) using outer product instead of catalogue.

Comment: @Bubbler Of course! That's much, much better!

Comment: Thanks for your two solutions +1 Why don't you have two different answers?

Comment: @RGS Well, I'm not sure... They turned out to be quite different.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
^þ/;RSS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/u8D5966Dg4P8Pd@6zftQwR0HXTuFRw1zrw@1ch9sfNa2J/P8/OtpUR8HELFZHIdpAR8HQCMQwgguZAYUMQQwTHQUjYxDD0FxHwdgSxAIqMjIHMYyNYEKGQGUmljCzTMFChkAWRJkBTNJCRwFMA40ygRhqDDTBODYWAA)

A monadic link taking a pair of integers and returning an integer.

A couple of alternative 7-byters:

[`Ż€^þ/SS`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7kdNa@IO79MPDv7/cOc@60cNcxR07RQeNcy1PtzOdbgdKBv5/390tKmOgolZrI5CtIGOgqERiGEEFzIDChmCGCY6CkbGIIahuY6CsSWIBVRkZA5iGBvBhAyBykwsYWaZgoUMgSyIMgOYpIWOApgGGmUCMdQYaIJxbCwA)
[`‘Ḷ^þ/SS`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yHO7bFHd6nHxz8/@HOfdaPGuYo6NopPGqYa324netw@6OmNZH//0dHm@oomJjF6ihEG@goGBqBGEZwITOgkCGIYaKjYGQMYhia6ygYW4JYQEVG5iCGsRFMyBCozMQSZpYpWMgQyIIoM4BJWugogGmgUSYQQ42BJhjHxgIA)

Comment: So short! Thanks for the alternatives +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 18 bytes

```
psqrzMPcp{q$$r[}ms
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY69CsIwFIX3@xQZBJcU7k9uklLwDRT36qK4WbEtXSx99ppE6vjxncM5t2l4PsZ@eqzPVzfvq6aprnvbNJd2mdf32A@f4/n@nvvdbmiXblyXazedVrXGeVMdjFckQGuIM4UI/FeCPhD45CijEoKzhiUDSUSgYI3UBV3ECKnJISMLIghvlmvN6VR2v3TU8BvVgpwkJSpdqtWD4JZ1FFQhWlMon02jrnwIXhhI0krBiMxf)

```
ps   # Parse to arr of ints
qrz  # Boxed range [0,N]
MP   # Map push
cp   # Cartesian product
{
 q$$ # Boxed xor
 r[  # Reduce by
}ms  # Map sum
```

Comment: Nice solution +1 Do the several letters together represent a single function name?

Comment: @RGS there's no such things as a function, it's all stack. The `q` is shorthand for putting it in a block. e.g. `qrz` = `{rz}`. Operations are elements of the stack too, and most operations are 2 chars. Some, like maps and reduce, take blocks of operations as an argument and apply them.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```c
R;f(x,y){R=++x*++y;for(y=0;--R;y+=R%x^R/x);x=y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLLasMwEEX3/YohELDjMdGMnka4H@F1KZQEhyzqltCFTci3u5IdeVl1I2ZzOHdG91RfTqd57nxfjDiV966tqvFQVZPvv27F1Apf152fqrbbj@/dcSz92E7@MX9@XIeivL98367DT1/s9nxGCA/Ur7A/vw07BI0AyiD0hUZlytIDHA9gtCA4HP8CRQCJIyiQOIHWZTAOwtXHSRgwKYzNCU0UUiQNEiWhJpHhVOBYRk4hy8SRdDmQLIJsIhgm2TyjknIit2Q8Ktv1qGyTkqXIKSUnZZg2JTc6HzasqdawCtUW1mn7r4/Uz4/U2304a6T1RMFISDYZG21yS4oUNUxbVEVW6wzpQlRYSIcLt1Yg21UbS75UwKLaKmCN5NyOAZILGCYpn1Gd4AV8zL8)

Comment: Thanks for your C submission +1

Comment: Nice! How does this work?

Comment: @S.S.Anne xnor has used the same algorithm for [his python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200180/90181) and written a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ô ï^Vô
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9CDvXlb0&input=NSw0Ng)

```
ô ï^Vô     :Implicit input of integers U & V
ô          :Range [0,U]
  ï        :Cartesian product with
    Vô     :Range [0,V]
   ^       :Reduce each pair by XORing
           :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Comment: I like the two eyes `ô` at the ends of the code +1

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 58 bytes

```java
(x,y)->{int t=++x*-~y;for(y=0;--t>0;)y+=t%x^t/x;return y;}
```

Port of [*@xibu*'s C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200181/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LVDRboIwFH33K25MlsC4MAqo0waTfcB88ZFg0lVccFhMKY6GsF9nLfhyTs5pe@7pvbIH86/nn5FXrGngk5WiXwCUQhXywngBBysnA7hjsUOL2qXGHxYGGsVUyeEAAtLR6VC7/r63d1Tqed2r/6fppZaOTkPq@2ofUld7qXrpTuqto7JQrRSg6TBSG3ZvvyoT9sx81OUZbqaTc1SyFN9ZDsydC9lIM8Q4HHYgil@YVJb3/QqT9YB9iCQyFD3lGgkxlGAUGyIbjLeGVxhtDMXRLEmCyXZ@u7KSIJmOw9l@R4sbTKaIGON4GNypDsBRN6q4BXWrgrvpqirhXM1yg1aVVfAhJdNNoOr5Hw53veUOlp4IuMOzMEeekdx97nQY/wE)

**Explanation:**

```java
(x,y)->{        // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  int t=++x     //  Increase `x` by 1 first with `++x`
        *-~y;   //  Create a temp integer `t`, with value `x*(y+1)`
  for(y=0;      //  Reset `y` to 0 to reuse as result-sum
      --t>0;)   //  Loop as long as `t-1` is larger than 0,
                //  decreasing it before every iteration with `--t`
    y+=         //   Increase the result-sum by:
       t%x      //    `t` modulo-`x`
          ^     //    Bitwise XOR-ed with:
           t/x; //    `t` integer-divided by `x`
  return y;}    //  And then return the result-sum `y`
```

Comment: Straightforward! Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 72 bytes

```clj
(defn s[x y](apply +(for[a(range(inc x))b(range(inc y))](bit-xor a b))))
```

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn sumxy[x y]
  (apply + (for [a (range (inc x))
                 b (range (inc y)) ]
              (bit-xor a b))))
```

Tests:

```clj
(println (s  5 46) " <-> "  6501)
(println (s  0 12) " <-> "    78)
(println (s 25 46) " <-> " 30671)
(println (s  6 11) " <-> "   510)
(println (s  4 23) " <-> "  1380)
(println (s 17 39) " <-> " 14808)
(println (s  5 27) " <-> "  2300)
(println (s 32 39) " <-> " 29580)
(println (s 14 49) " <-> " 18571)
(println (s  0 15) " <-> "   120)
(println (s 11 17) " <-> "  1956)
(println (s 30 49) " <-> " 41755)
(println (s  8  9) " <-> "   501)
(println (s  7 43) " <-> "  7632)
(println (s 13 33) " <-> "  8022)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHLasMwEEX3@YpLVxIloBk9DaE/ErKwU6e4GNkoKdhf73gXSakWAsHh3Duj6zj9/qV@28R3f4u4nxesF9HO87jiE@I2pXMrUht/ejHEKxYpu@y5SnkR3fA4LlNCi07u53AQcxriY4wQd8DCOIkPnI5f@w1nFcmSUCDOCMCHkuDSoZXztcOBKHdYUhVhwDojSIeKIA/dvAgyQVU99lnYZw7WqnJoLhzc2LcUA5OnBOv/2YfNZyGuHbSXzWdprKt6qCLFkLe2SglAU2zs7V88TL4x7zRXPTR0TgTFLLftCQ)

Comment: So many parenthesis :p +1

Comment: Lisp (of which Clojure is a variant) was one of the earliest high-level languages. It probably would have been more widely adopted were it not for the high costs incurred by the untimely post-war depletion of the Strategic Parenthesis Reserve. However, despite such setbacks, Lisp and its derivatives have been influential in key algorithmic techniques such as recursion and condescension. [See the "...History of Programming Languages" page](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html). :-)

Comment: I don't think I even understand all the jokes and references, but that blog post is making me laugh so much :D thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

Takes input as `(x)(y)` (or the other way around). Computes the sum recursively, the obvious way.

```javascript
x=>g=(y,Y=y)=>~x&&(x^y)+g(y?y-1:x--&&Y,Y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBasMwEEX3PYVXZobGjWakkeSC0nN4UwhpYlJCXJpSrE2v7jpIJUXO@vH@nz/v2@/tZfd5/PhqzsPbfjqEaQybPkBcdSFi2PyMdQ3ja8THHuJLbOh5bJq67lYdTrvhfBlO@6fT0MMBKkEwFrFarysrih4KrBCIE3a@gPzP1cq6hWxnmRIXUiU1CKwTJe1LTA5Btxkbr8ry6@HsEmetSl3zTedWlvFzu/mL9@LuDpfMeWETXg9MtBVblqtbuCEnUoZ7hCrzOz@fl5v8GGc1l916XpaxV8zTLw)

Comment: Good answer! I thought you were going to find some weird formula with the bits of `x` and `y`! Nothing came to mind?

Comment: @RGS The carries implied by a sum usually doesn't mix well with bitwise operations. So I doubt a magic formula exists. (But I'd love to see one.)

Comment: If time efficiency were the goal, there are some simple formulas that come quite close (and can then be corrected by brute-forcing a much shorter list).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>59</s></sup> 58 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) and [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino)!!!

```python
lambda x,y:sum(a^b for a in range(x+1)for b in range(y+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNaoQwFIX3PsXFVUJTyK9RwS77BN31B2IntgMzKuqAIj67vYlTZiHxO/eck0v6ZfrtWrU31cd@cdf65GBmSznersR91dB0Azg4tzC49seT@UnQINUPaUGJ7kO1vg03X0LqxpTBq7uMAdpuAhS2JISwl/kQJAkBw0BnDDLDBWXInIGQDGweSN6nimf2GCMIwcAIHlEzkAollUcWFr0Fss55LAj10gYTjwYlD4MszD2BDTokcmMfC5iwxDHHy0KrKEwWC/jh18IaE/05A0Dhf3/0atzIZkrGPP4r/HIuA9MygX44txNp0nUu5cZgXfCA5xdYG4IvQ0uzwTq8H1BV/nMDP/f@e/KnlO5/)

Comment: You have an extra space that you can remove after the `)` in `range(x+1)`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>61</s></sup> 52 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
b;s;f(x,y){for(s=b=y;~x;b--||(b=y,x--))s+=x^b;s-=y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLPasMwDIfvewpRKCSdTC35bwjdk4zB2pHRw7rR7pDSdq@eyUmd47yLkUk@vp9k7dT7bjcM2/bUdlWP5/rSfR6r02a7Obc/fbtV6nqt5IK9UnV9etz0L/Kvkq@34eN1f6jqy8PXcX/47qrFkt8Q5AD1BMu358MCwSGA9Qhd5dD6um4B1ivwThOs1n@BWkDiBGokzmCIBYxFOPk4CwUz2oeS0CchJdIjURY60gXOCscmcRbZZI5MLIEUEEyTQKlMc49KNupSk2moHKahcshKNrqkNJyVUs1Kblw5rLRpp7AW7Rw2uvCvh3T3h3TzfLhopGlEYiSkkI2N86UmdY4q1RzVUnCuQEaJCiMZceSmFSjuakhLPq5AQDuvQPCGSz0KZEZQKmPuUaPmEbwNvw)

Comment: Do you really have to have the three variables before the `f`? Can't you stuff them somewhere else or something? :/

Comment: @RGS Tried several variations and they had either more or the same byte count. :(

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZLNasMwEITvfQoRCNjpimhXv8a4T1IKdYJDDnVL3INDkr66u3Ys00uVixghfcyMVjt52O2GoS67ssl6OOeX5vOUdVVdncufvqylvF4z3kAvZZ53z1X/xncln96Gj/djm@WXp6/Tsf1ustV6D2K9F/KF19d2BcKCMA5Ek1kwLs9Lsd0IZxWKzfZfSIFAGhkFSDPjQ4qgxYb@@GjlfNKICcSRcoA4QxZVCjEgSI@IAdIzgjokGfQgdDFCrHQRKRNUshR3In9/OvIzRFolrTRFK1aLFRX2QUKuZe4JDZglYbD@4aDsPCgbIUo78Xvj1IoVxlpYWJespWI@Vks@g97aFBZATFCAiDz4eRzMTNP1YOJ0vdOUbMSAniBWOlJB0UTdhl8)

Comment: @Arnauld That's diabolical - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
Sum[i~BitXor~j,{i,0,#},{j,0,#2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P7g0NzqzzimzJCK/qC5LpzpTx0BHuVanOgtEG9XGqv0PKMrMK1FwSI821TExi/3/HwA)

Comment: Thanks for this! Also, be sure to check out [this Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200188/75323)!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ò@Vò^XÃc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=8kBW8l5Yw2M&input=NQo0Ng)

Comment: 8 bytes: `ò@Vò^XÃc`.

Comment: I also like the eyes and nose here: `ò@ò`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
eval '<<<$[' +{0..$1}^{0..$2} ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanBVZxaoqBboaCgoKyQll@k4JKaVJquUJZZXJqYk1mVWJKZn6eQn5dT@T@1LDFHQd3GxkYlWl1Bu9pAT0/FsDYOTBvVKsT@1@TiSlMwVTAx@w8A)

Uses `eval` to expand the `<<<$[` `]` after expanding the lists. The TIO link adds `set -x` so you can see what the brace expansion looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your zsh submission!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 36 bytes

```perl
map{//;map$\+=$_^$',0..$F[0]}0..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaX98aSKnEaNuqxMepqOsY6OmpuEUbxNYCGTZ2tdX//5tymZj9yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F@3IBEA)

Takes in inputs on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks for your Perl 5 submission! Why did you go for Perl 5 and not any other version? Like a more recent version?

Comment: @RGS Perl 5 is very different from Perl 6, so much so that the latter has been renamed to Raku to prevent confusion. Perl 5 is what most people refer to as just Perl

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 126 bytes

This isn't a golfing language and it doesn't have a bitwise XOR operator but:

```sql
SELECT SUM(x+y-2*BITAND(x,y))FROM(SELECT LEVEL-1 x FROM T CONNECT BY LEVEL<x+2),(SELECT LEVEL-1 y FROM T CONNECT BY LEVEL<y+2)
```

Assumes that there is a table `T` with columns `X` and `Y` containing one row that has the input values.

So for the inputs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(x,y) AS SELECT 5,46 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | SUM(X+Y-2*BITAND(X,Y)) |
> | ---------------------: |
> |                   6501 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48a954394774b113027ebb635c07d6a3)*

---

As an aside, its only 81 characters in PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT sum(a#b)FROM t,generate_series(0,t.x)AS x(a),generate_series(0,t.y)AS y(b)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e34aca835030c0dea9a6ae26ef19c04c)*

But its less fun as that has a built-in XOR operator and series generation.

Comment: Really cool solution! thanks for it +1

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
(x,y)->sum(i⊻j for i=0:x,j=0:y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvtfo0KnUlPXrrg0VyPzUdfuLIW0/CKFTFsDqwqdLCBZqfm/oCgzryQnTyNNw1THxExTkwshYKBjaKSp@R8A)

Comment: This Julia answer is really short +1 good job

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
d,r;f(x,y){for(d=y;~d||(x--,d=y),~x;)r+=x^d--;d=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBDYAwCAXQdSDyJyCs4gVSjyacaKxdHX2357jcu0NSB5VMfsadFDZ1x1pUgPxh2aWch9UZgIalvt0f)

Comment: Nice answer! +1 keep up the good work

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9Fp8g6TaNCp1KzOi2/SCPFttJasS7FHkhbVWhr61RYaxZp2@rqVsSl6Opap9gWWdf@z03MzNPQrC4oyswrSdNQUk2JyVPSSdMw1TEx09QEygMA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")